# How gridview row deleting for nested gridview

Tags: asp.net

I have a a gridview  `GridViewTranstoCon` inside a main gridview `GridViewTtransmittals`.
Now for `GridViewTranstoCon_RowDeleting` I have written the code below, but it is failing.

```
protected void GridViewTranstoCon_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    GridView TranstoCon = GridViewTtransmittals.FindControl("GridViewTranstoCon") as GridView;


    OnDeleteTtransmittaltocon(Convert.ToInt32(TranstoCon.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value));
        }


private void OnDeleteTtransmittaltocon(int transmittoconid,int transid)
{
    if (DeleteTransmittaltocon != null)
    {
        DeleteTransmittaltocon(this, new tbltranstoconEventArgs { TransmittoconID = transmittoconid, TransID = transid });
      //  DeleteTransmittaltocon(this, new tbltranstoconEventArgs { TransmittoconID = transmittoconid });
    }
}
```

And my event handler is like below , I do not know how to add another aegument.

```
public class tbltransmittalNoEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public int TransID { get; set; }
}

public class tbltranstoconEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public int TransmittoconID { get; set; }
    public int TransID { get; set; }

}

public event EventHandler<tbltranstoconEventArgs> DeleteTransmittaltocon;
```

What can I do?

Comment: please help what is the problem. bacause i am new to asp.net.some code or sample will be very good for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, the sender should be the GridView that was clickeed

```
protected void GridViewTranstoCon_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    //Put a breakpoint after this line, what is value of Id, TranstoCon
    GridView TranstoCon = sender as GridView;
    int Id = Convert.ToInt32(TranstoCon.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);

    //Also step into this and see what it's doing
    OnDeleteTtransmittaltocon(Id);

}
```

Comment: i added the code, there is no error, but delete button does not work.

Comment: can you step through your code in debug mode and see the value of every variable e.g. the RowIndex, the GridView etc. Put a breakpoint in there. See my update

Comment: thanks it helped me alot, just i have error Delegate 'EventHandler' does not take '3' arguments". i updated my code in the above please help how i can solve the problem

Comment: I think here: `DeleteTransmittaltocon(this, new tbltranstoconEventArgs { TransmittoconID = transmittoconid }, new tbltransmittalNoEventArgs { TransID = transid });` you were passing 3 arguments to `DeleteTransmittaltocon` which does not take 3 arguments - it should be lesser or more

Comment: thanks, i add transid to my class properties and a bit changing in the code like above , now is working.